# equality between two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code and I am wondering why when (a) array changes then the other will change two is that because of pointers?

```
Boolean[] a= {false,false};
Boolean[] b = {false,false};
a = b;
a[0] = true;
b[1] = true;

System.out.println(a[0] +" "+ b[0]);
System.out.println(a[1] +" "+ b[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
true true
true true
```

Comment: what do you think `a = b;` does?

Comment: Yes it is because of pointers, with the line:  a = b; you are literally telling Java to point the reference of a to the value of b in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's reason is pointers. Variable a and b is points same positions because

```
a = b;
```

After this code a points same memory adress with b. And all the changes and result will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set `a = b` both point to the same data. Hence if you change one, you change the other. They are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No specific to arrays. It is how object assignment works in java.
You assign to the variable `a` the same reference that the variable `b` here  :

```
a = b;
```

So `a` and `b` variables refer to the same object after this statement.

To make `a` and `b` refer two distinct objects, you have to copy values of them.
For an array of Boolean (immutable) : the `clone()` method that makes a shallow copy is a way.

```
a = b.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes because of the pointers

You first create two arrays and gave them two pointers a and b, one for each of the arrays.
When you did a=b now your 'a' pointer has the same value of b so they both point to the second array, thus both a and b are now the same thing.

This also means that you no longer can change the first array, since there is no pointer pointing at it, and the array memory should be freed